# PHP: How can one find the time difference in seconds between values "2022-06-24T15:04:37.000000Z" and "2022-06-24 15:05:15", e.g. using strtotime()?

Tags: php, date, time, timezone, strtotime

I am using an API that is giving me two time values to describe its execution, but in different formats. For instance:

```
'created_at' => '2022-06-24T15:04:37.000000Z',
'processed_at' => '2022-06-24 15:05:15',
```

I am running the code:

```
$created = "2022-06-24T15:04:37.000000Z";
$processed = "2022-06-24 15:05:15";
$createdtime = strtotime($created);
$processedtime = strtotime($processed);
$diff = $processedtime - $createdtime;
echo "Created: $created Processed: $processed createdtime: $createdtime processedtime: $processedtime Diff: $diff<br/>\n";
```

On two different servers, to test how to find the difference in seconds between these two times. One on server it gives me the results:

```
Created: 2022-06-24T15:04:37.000000Z Processed: 2022-06-24 15:05:15 createdtime: 1656083077 processedtime: 1656083115 Diff: 38
```

On another server, it says:

```
Created: 2022-06-24T15:04:37.000000Z Processed: 2022-06-24 15:05:15 createdtime: 1656083077 processedtime: 1656097515 Diff: 14438
```

I am assuming that this is a timezone issue. 14400 seconds=10 hours. The "real" answer should be 38, as that's how long the API took in real life to process the request. Is there any code I could use to get a consistent result of 38 seconds across the two servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`processed_at` doesn't contain a timezone, so PHP is using whatever it has configured as default. It looks like the timezone of `processed_at` is supposed to be UTC, so I'd just force it. You could just add a `Z` to the end of the string:

```
$processedtime = strtotime($processed . ' Z');
```

Or, more correctly, tell PHP to use UTC when no timezone is otherwise available in the string:

```
$processedtime = (new DateTime($processed, new DateTimeZone('UTC')))->format('U');
```

[Update]

> Is there a way to check if a string has a blank TZ?

Yes, but it's easier to just use the default mechanism of the DateTime class. For example, if you do this:

```
$timestamp1 = new DateTime($string1, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
```

Then this default timezone will *only* be applied if string doesn't explicitly contain one. But if you do this:

```
$timestamp1 = new DateTime($string1);
$timestamp1->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
```

Then you will always explicitly set the timezone, possibly changing it from the original specified. If you do both:

```
$timestamp1 = new DateTime($string1, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$timestamp1->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
```

Then you're saying, "consider this string to be UTC if it doesn't contain timezone, and then convert it to UTC if it did contain a timezone that wasn't UTC."

> Is there maybe any way to check if DateTime generated a timezone for an input string?

You can pull out the timezone that was used in the previous step and apply it as the default for the second timestamp, if that second timestamp doesn't also include an explicit timezone:

```
$timestamp1 = new DateTime($string1, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$timestamp2 = new DateTime($string2, $timestamp1->getTimezone());
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But what about a more general case, where you might get a blank TZ for one string, and any TZ for the other string? And you could be getting the blank string in either order? If the first string has no TZ and the second has a different TZ than the server, what do you do? Is there a way to check if a string has a blank TZ? That way I can use conditions, if the first string has no TZ and the second string does, assume the first string has the same TZ as the second. But, I don't know how to check if a string has a TZ before you send it to DateTime.

Comment: The problem I'm confused on is, if the first string is blank, DateTime will use the default TZ. And the second string might have some other TZ than the default. And you can't set the default time zone to the second string's before you use the first time zone, since you haven't gotten to the second string yet. I found how to check if a string is a valid TZ, but not how to check if a string contains a valid TZ. Is there maybe any way to check if DateTime generated a timezone for an input string?

Comment: [Answer updated.]